# How can I remove unit tag from URL in contact form 7 plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, contact-form-7

I had added Contact form 7 in my project but I am facing a problem, problem is #wpcf7-f182-o1 is coming with url when I click on contact form 7 send button...what is this and how can we remove this problem ? Please help...Thanks in advance.

Comment: when form submitted this `url /#wpcf7-f182-o1` will redirected to same page, the reason is reporting error message or success message in end of form

Comment: yes my page is redirect on same page , By the way...my all fields are empty like name,email,message. But how can we remove ??

Answer (score 5):

Add below code to your `functions.php` and it will remove it.

```
add_filter('wpcf7_form_action_url', 'remove_unit_tag');

function remove_unit_tag($url){
    $remove_unit_tag = explode('#',$url);
    $new_url = $remove_unit_tag[0];
    return $new_url;
}
```

Comment: This is working as well. Thanks alot to @Rohil_PHPBeginner

Comment: works perfectly thank you so much, had been looking all over the internet for something like this but couldn't find anything!